# how to add background image to box in mui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a background image to Box component of mui but it dosen't work I am providing my code

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Box 
     sx={{backgroundImage:'images/cover.jpeg'}}
     height='385px'
    >
      
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not far from it.  You just need to add the path to the file preceded by `url`, for example:

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        backgroundImage: "url('images/cover.jpeg')",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        height: '385px',
        width: '385px'
      }}
    >
    
    </Box>
  );
};
```

*(assuming `images/cover.jpeg` is the correct path to your image.)*

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-box-background-image-wcseex?file=/demo.js

Comment: FYI: I added `no-repeat` just for kicks -- you can omit that if you want the background image to repeat (tile).

Answer (score 3):

You are well on track. To employ this successfully, you can proceed as follows;

```
import  cover from "./images/cover.jpeg";
 const Main = () => {
  return (
   <Box
   sx={{
    backgroundImage:`url(${cover})`,
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    height: "385px",
    }}
   >
   <Box/>
  )    
}
```

The assumption here is that the path provided for the import is correct("./images/cover.jpeg"). You can supply additional styling such as width to the image as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Box
          sx={{
            backgroundImage: `url("./images/cover.jpeg")`,
            backgroundPosition: `right bottom`,
            backgroundRepeat: `no-repeat`,
            backgroundSize: `300px 300px`,
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
          }}
        > 
      
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Make sure image url is correct and need to give some size to adjust the layout

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
<Box sx={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${calltoActionBg.src})`,
        }}>CallToAction</Box>
```

Without the ".src" it was rendering as [Object,Object]